# building gtkmm-3-22 on ubuntu with jhbuild (issues)

Tags: gtk3

I have been trying to build gtkmm-3-22 with jhbuild. i did everything before building gtkmm (i.e: jhbuild sysdep bootstrap sanitycheck etc) so now, i come acrros an error:

```
> make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'desktopappinfo.cc', needed by
> 'desktopappinfo.lo'.  Stop. make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished
> jobs....   CXX      zlibcompressor.lo make[2]: Leaving directory
> '/home/mdr/jhbuild/checkout/glibmm/gio/giomm' Makefile:711: recipe for
> target 'all-recursive' failed make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mdr/jhbuild/checkout/glibmm'
> Makefile:507: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2
> *** Error during phase build of glibmm: ########## Error running make -j 2  *** [9/23]
> 
>   [1] Rerun phase build   [2] Ignore error and continue to install  
> [3] Give up on module   [4] Start shell   [5] Reload configuration  
> [6] Go to phase "wipe directory and start over"   [7] Go to phase
> "configure"   [8] Go to phase "clean"   [9] Go to phase "distclean"
> choice:
```

full log: https://pastebin.com/UTGJzHjy

can you help me please?
best regards.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? For example 17.10 and 18.04 already have the [3.22 version in repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libgtkmm-3.0-dev&searchon=names).

Comment: my version is 16.04. document says it is possible to install another version with jhbuild. and it's not interferes to system libraries.